# Getting Error - Could not find or load main class makingachange.Main in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am getting this error - **Could not find or load main class makingachange.Main**   whenever I try to run the program, I dont understand why it is showing me this error as I am really a newbie in Java. Can someone please help me in trying to fix this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
package makingachange;

public class Main {
    private int[] denom;
    Main( int[] denom) {
        this.denom = denom;
    }
    void giveChange(int changeRs) {
        System.out.println("\nChange for " + changeRs + " in Rs " + ":");
        for(int i = 0; i < denom.length; ++i) { int nb = changeRs / denom[i]; if(nb > 0)
                System.out.println(nb + " " + denom[i]);
            changeRs %= denom[i];
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                 int[] Rs = {100,50,20,10,5,1};
                Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter the purchase amount : ");
                int purchaseAmount=input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter the amount given by customer : ");
                int AmountGivenByCusto=input.nextInt();
                if(AmountGivenByCusto<purchaseAmount){
                    System.out.println("Sorry! you paid less than purchase amount!  ");
                }else
{
                int result=AmountGivenByCusto-purchaseAmount;
        Main change1 = new Main( Rs);
        change1.giveChange(result);
                }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First there is an error

`package` statement should be the first statement so it should be this

```
package makingachange;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

then you have to generate package first

```
javac -d . Main.java

java  makingchange/Main.java
```

`-d` mean create package

`.` mean generate use path of current directory to generate package

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the package definition is written before the import of `java.util.Scanner`. Double check if the package in your workspace has exactly the same name as the package you define in your class (so in this case: `makingachange`).

The following code works for me.

```
package makingachange;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private int[] denom;

    Main(int[] denom) {
        this.denom = denom;
    }

    void giveChange(int changeRs) {
        System.out.println("\nChange for " + changeRs + " in Rs " + ":");
        for (int i = 0; i < denom.length; ++i) {
            int nb = changeRs / denom[i];
            if (nb > 0)
                System.out.println(nb + " " + denom[i]);
            changeRs %= denom[i];
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] Rs = { 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1 };
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the purchase amount : ");
        int purchaseAmount = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the amount given by customer : ");
        int AmountGivenByCusto = input.nextInt();
        if (AmountGivenByCusto < purchaseAmount) {
            System.out.println("Sorry! you paid less than purchase amount!  ");
        } else {
            int result = AmountGivenByCusto - purchaseAmount;
            Main change1 = new Main(Rs);
            change1.giveChange(result);
        }
    }
}
```